# Extracting page id from a facebook page url

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application where when a user enters their facebook fan page url, I extract the page id and store that into the database to be used later in facebook graph api.

I have added the following js to extract page id:

```
<script>
 var fburl= "https://www.facebook.com/audi";
 if(fburl.indexOf("?") != -1) {
        var fburl_new=fburl.split("/");
        var fburl_newer=(fburl_new[fburl_new.length-1])
        var fburl_newer =fburl_newer.split("?");
        var fbnameonly=(fburl_newer[fburl_newer.length-2]);
    } else {
        var fbnameonly = fburl.substring(fburl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    }
 if(fbnameonly==undefined) {
        console.log(fburl);
 }else {
        console.log(fbnameonly);
 }
</script>
```

So, if I a user enters a facebook url like: `https://www.facebook.com/audi`, I get the output `audi` which is fine.

If a user enters facebook url as : `https://www.facebook.com/pages/abc-def/1234568`, I get the output `1234568` which is fine.

but for urls like:

`https://www.facebook.com/abc-def-12345678/` (should return 12345678)

or

`https://www.facebook.com/audi/timeline?ref=page_internal` (should return audi)

I am unable to get the page id, is there any better way by which I can extract page id from any facebook fan page url and use it in facebook graph api like: `https://graph.facebook.com/page_id` dynamically ?

Comment: Regex [`\.com\/(?:pages\/)?([\w-]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fH1oF4/1)

Comment: @Tushar that won't work for any urls like `https://www.facebook.com/Lo-stile-di-Anna-1521824524722026` here `1521824524722026` is the page id that I can use with graph api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a better way to get page id from any facebook page url, I am not sure if there is even better option to do this but here is the code what I have used:

```
$fbUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/Lo-stile-di-Anna-1521824524722026";
$graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/?id=".$fbUrl."&access_token=xxxxx&fields=id";
$output = file_get_contents($graphUrl);
$output = json_decode($output, TRUE);
echo $output["id"]; // returns 1521824524722026
```

I tried this with various facebook urls and it worked everytime, hope this helps someone in the future.