# Facebook - get page id with/without access token

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Their is a way to get a facebook page id via get request? Or i need to send also a access token ?

For the second option. I have a facebook application. How i can get the facebook page id?

I use this code ([Extracting page id from a facebook page url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339375/extracting-page-id-from-a-facebook-page-url)):

```
$fbUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/Lo-stile-di-Anna-
1521824524722026";
$graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/?id=".$fbUrl."&access_token=xxxxx&fields=id";
$output = file_get_contents($graphUrl);
$output = json_decode($output, TRUE);
echo $output["id"]; // returns 1521824524722026
```

As you can see i need the access_token parameter. How can i obtain it automatically (via script call) or how can it stay permanent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an App Access Token, it is just a combination of App ID and App Secret with a pipe sign: `App-ID|App-Secret`

You get the ID of a page with this API call: `graph.facebook.com/bladauhu?access_token?xxx`

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: You make my day :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the facebook SDK in past but with PHP.

Every request need that you have an access token setted and a facebook app id configured. So, i think that it's not possible to access the resource you need without a token.

Read the facebook API documentation for more info about [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples)